# Where is the non-convertible delegate return type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, delegates

Trying to use a delegate to return a service from my DI container, based on a type set on an attribute on an enum, but running into CS1662 errors, where some of the return types are not implicitly convertible. I can't see where the issue is.

The delegate looks like this, where the key is expected to be a `ParserType`, which in turn is decorated with the `ParserTypeInfoAttribute`, which provides the property `ServiceType`, which sets the IValueParser type to retrieve from the container.

I'm doing it this way as the ParserType enum may grow in future, so I don't want to have multiple switches in the code to find properties related to the enum value, instead they're defined on the ParserTypeInfo attribute and modified/set there only. I think generic attributes would save me, but that's not an option yet (C# 10).

How can I make this work?

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<Func<ParserType, IValueParser>>(serviceProvider => key =>
{
  IValueParser serviceType = (key as ParserType).GetAttribute<ParserTypeInfoAttribute>()?.ServiceType;

  if (serviceType == null) 
    throw new Exception();

  return serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
});
```

```cs
// attribute
[ParserTypeInfo(typeof(StringValueParser))]
// implementation
public class ParserTypeInfoAttribute : Attribute
{
  internal ParserTypeInfoAttribute(Type serviceType)
  {
    ServiceType = serviceType as IValueParser;
  }

  public Type ServiceType { get; private set; }
}
```

Edit - works fine, if I'm not mixing types:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<Func<ParserType, IValueParser>>(serviceProvider => key =>
{
  Type serviceType = (key as ParserType).GetAttribute<ParserTypeInfoAttribute>()?.ServiceType;

  if (serviceType == null) 
    throw new Exception();

  // given I know the ParserType key will have a corresponding parser available on the container, this cast is safe.
  return serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType) as IValueParser;
});
```

Comment: If `Type` is `System.Type` then it doesn't implement `IValueParser`. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Should `serviceProvider.GetInstance` be `serviceProvider.GetService`?

Comment: @JonSkeet yup, it should - that's poor copypasta on my part. Will update the question.

Comment: Okay, and what do you believe the compile-time return type of `serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType)` is? Your anonymous function has to return an `IValueParser` - it doesn't at the moment. As an aside, it looks like you're using `IValueParser` as both the type and the instance... that's at least part of the problem (and is behind Llama's comment too).

Comment: @Llama my fault, transcription error. Attribute property is System.Type, not IValueParser

Comment: Is `IValueParser serviceType = (key as ParserType).GetAttribute<ParserTypeInfoAttribute>()?.ServiceType;` also a transcription error then?

Comment: @JonSkeet return type will be IValueParser. I think fixing the errors raised above resolves it, I'm blaming my lacking attention when switching between two different DI containers.

Comment: The return type of `GetService` is `object`.

Comment: @Llama yes, I'm juggling MS DI and LightInject in a dual-targeted build, and stepping on my own toes. Thanks for the clarity though, looks like it's all good when I sort out my types

Comment: You may expect the value returned to be a reference to an `IValueParser` instance, but what makes you think the *compile-time* type is `IValueParser`? (I'd also note that if you've got multiple DI frameworks involved, you should really say so and provide a [mcve] which includes package references and all using directives etc. It's hard to help you with copy/paste errors and unknown dependencies.)

Comment: If I control the ParserType enum implementation, and therefore control the type passed into the attribute and used to get the service, isn't it safe that the compile-time type would be IValueParser? What would be a scenario where it wouldn't be IValueParser? Will check though that the service is assignable to IValueParser.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to use casts rather than `as` when you fully expect the value to be of the appropriate type. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/

Comment: @Nathan: "isn't it safe that the compile-time type would be IValueParser" - um, no. How do you expect the *compiler* to know that? Have you looked at the definition of `IServiceProvider.GetService`? How would a non-generic method just accepting a `Type` parameter know *at compile-time* that the returned value should be `IValueParser`? Note that this is a misunderstanding of C# itself, not dependency injection. When the declared return type of a method is just `object`, you can't expect the compiler to ignore that and just expect what you want.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, that makes total sense. Appreciate your help.